# Edit the classess applied to a field from outside the field template

Tags: theming, entities, panels

I am creating my own [Panels Style Plugins](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

The styles are applied to a Panel Pane which contains a field.

From the Style, I can add a wrapper DIV to modify the display of the field.

However, I would like to be able to modify the actual class on the field itself (this would negate the need for a wrapper DIV).

In my field.tpl.php file I have placed a PHP variable for the class, but I'm not sure how I can access and modify this variable from outside the field.tpl.php file. Could some one give me some pointers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Semantic Panels](http://drupal.org/project/semantic_panels). It lets you choose HTML element and classes for wrapper, the field and the label. The module provides the same options that are available to customize the field output in Views.

Here's a screenshot from the user interface when you customize the field.

[image: Semantic Panels - settings]

Comment: Thanks! Can I use that to manipulate the class from my Panel style (e.g. the class should only be added if the panel style is active). Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Semantic Panels is a style on it's own so yes, it will only add your settings when active.

Comment: it doesn't seem to let you modify the classes applied to fields contained within the Pane. Is that possible, or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did you choose Semantic panels as style? What settings did you change? Content, wrapper?

Comment: It seems that module only adds a wrapper with the class to the field. It doesn't add it to the actual field.  e.g. `<a class="field" href="#"></a>` would become `<div class="mynewclass"><a class="field" href="#"></a></div>` instead of `<a class="field mynewclass" href="#"></a>`

Comment: Yes if the field content itself contains that a tag you can not modify it. It's the same functionality as Views provides basically.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to it via [hook_preprocess_HOOK](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) . Try to dpm($vars), classes should be one of them, you will then be able to change it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm not quite sure how to use this. I tried panels_preprocess_HOOK & panels_preprocess_field in my Panel Style, but this didn't do anything. I then tried panels_preprocess, which displays an array, which has a theme_hook_suggestion field of `panels_pane__entity_field` and `panels_pane__entity_field__node:field_call_to_action`. However, neither of these work. Also, once I have made a class for my field, how do I get it to display in field.tpl.php (the class should only appear when the panels style is in use).

Comment: are you doing the style in a module ?

Comment: It's a panels plugin which I have put in my theme (as apparently panels plugins go in the theme folder).  Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: then the hook name should start with your theme name : YOUR_THEME_preprocess_field

Comment: Thanks for your help! That works, but it effects all fields. I only want to target one field (called `call to action`). When I use `YOUR_THEME_preprocess_field` it gives the following theme_hook_suggestions: `field__field_call_to_action`  ,  `field__field_call_to_action__content`. I have tried prefixing each of these with `THEMENAME_preprocess_field` ,  `THEMENAME_preprocess_`  and  `THEMENAME_field` but it seems to have no effect. Thanks for any guidance you can offer, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: i think that you will either have to check the field name in the general field hook ($vars['element'][#field_name] == 'field_call_to_action'), or add the field to the theme registry

Comment: Thanks! How do I add a field to theme registry. I tried searching for tutorials but couldn't find anything. Also, once it is added, how do I access it from field.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use preprocess_panels_pane(). I use it to remove the default classes from Panels.

```
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_panels_pane($vars) {
  $content = $vars['output'];
  // basic classes
  $vars['classes'] = '';
  $vars['id'] = '';

  ctools_include('cleanstring');

  // Add id and custom class if sent in.
  if (!empty($content->content)) {
    if (!empty($content->css_id)) {
      $vars['id'] = ' id="' . $content->css_id . '"';
    }
    if (!empty($content->css_class)) {
      $vars['classes'] .= $content->css_class;
    }
  }

  // administrative links, only if there is permission.
  $vars['admin_links'] = '';
  if (user_access('view pane admin links') && !empty($content->admin_links)) {
    $vars['admin_links'] = theme('links', $content->admin_links);
  }

  $vars['title'] = !empty($content->title) ? $content->title : '';

  $vars['feeds'] = !empty($content->feeds) ? implode(' ', $content->feeds) : '';
  $vars['content'] = !empty($content->content) ? $content->content : '';  

  $vars['links'] = !empty($content->links) ? theme('links', $content->links) : '';
  $vars['more'] = '';
  if (!empty($content->more)) {
    if (empty($content->more['title'])) {
      $content->more['title'] = t('more');
    }
    $vars['more'] = l($content->more['title'], $content->more['href'], $content->more);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! How do I make it work so only my Panel style creates the variable that can then be passed into my field.tpl.php file. If I use `THEME_NAME_preprocess_panels_pane($vars)`, it will make all Panel styles effect the output and not just my current style. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood exactly what you were trying to do... This might be an odd question but are you using theme_PLUGINNAME_STYLENAME_style_render_pane()? Can you not access it from there?

Comment: No, the only one that seems to work is  `panels_preprocess()`.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as it's just a field that you're trying to alter, have you tried the [Field Formatter Class](http://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_class) module?

> This module allows site administrators to add classes to the outer
>   HTML wrapper for any field display.
>
> Classes can be specified at the Manage display settings for content
>   types, users and other entities.

On a side note, the [Fences](http://drupal.org/project/fences) module doesn't add classes to your fields, but it is WELL worth knowing about if you want to reduce the markup/div soup that Drupal adds.

Comment: This module seems to change the class on the field, but it effects all fields and not just the one that has my panel style.